# Insert data into database(MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, insert, record

I am trying to insert datas to Appointment table of my database. I did registration part of my project which works well. There are 2 tables, Patient and Appointment. After Login patients can make an appointment. Patient number comes like this

```
 MyUser.PatientNo = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
```

For appointment date and description comes from textbox. And I want to insert PatientNo from Patient table to Appointment table. For me it looks done but when I choose date and write description but I got error on this line `app.PatientNo = patient.PatientNo;`

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DentAppSys.dll but was not handled in user code

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Make(Models.AppModel User)
        {
            if (Session["UserEmail"] != null)
            {
                using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                {


                    var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                    var app = new Appointment();
                    app.Date = User.Date;
                    app.Description = User.Description;
                    app.Status = "true";
                    app.PatientNo = patient.PatientNo;
                    db.Appointments.InsertOnSubmit(app);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Make", "Appointment");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and this is registration part which is working well

```
public ActionResult RegAndLogin(Models.RegAndLog User)
        {
            if (User.RegisterModel != null)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                    {
                        var Person = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == User.RegisterModel.Email);
                        if (Person == null)
                        {
                            string Hash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(User.RegisterModel.Password);
                            var MyUser = new Patient();
                            MyUser.Name = User.RegisterModel.Firstname;
                            MyUser.Surname = User.RegisterModel.Lastname;
                            MyUser.Birthday = User.RegisterModel.Birthday;
                            MyUser.Email = User.RegisterModel.Email;
                            MyUser.Password = Hash;
                            MyUser.PatientNo = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
                            db.Patients.InsertOnSubmit(MyUser);
                            db.SubmitChanges();

                            Session["UserEmail"] = User.RegisterModel.Email;
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patient", User.RegisterModel);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "There is a user with this Email. Please enter another Email !!!");
                            return View();
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Data is incorrect !!!");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid && IsValid(User.LoginModel.Email, User.LoginModel.Password))
                {
                    var TempUser = new Models.RegisterModel();
                    Session["UserEmail"] = User.LoginModel.Email;
                    using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                    {
                        var person = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == User.LoginModel.Email);
                        TempUser.Firstname = person.Name;
                        TempUser.Lastname = person.Surname;
                        //TempUser.RegisterModel.Birthday = (DateTime)person.BirthDate;
                        TempUser.Email = person.Email;


                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patient", TempUser);


                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Check your E-mail or Password then try again !!!");
                }
            }
            return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a null exception on the line

```
app.PatientNo = patient.PatientNo;
```

It will be because either app or patient are null at when it's executed. I would suspect patient.

Check that patient is found correctly at the line

```
var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
```

if it isn't found patient will be null.

Comment: I checked database.I login with asd@gmail.com pasword:asd .In Patient table that record has PatientNo so it s not null but when I want toget that PatientNo to write App table ,it doesnt work

Comment: Maybe Session["UserEmail"] is not as you expect. Have you set it to the correct email address. Best way to check would be to put a breakpoint just after that statement and check the contents of app, patients, Session["UserEmail"] and I'm sure you'll find one of them isn't as expected. If they are check patients.PatientNo at that point in time too.

Comment: Also check db.Patients has the data rather than directly in the database.